# How can I serve an image in django?

Tags: django

I have a binary field to save images

```
    photograph = models.BinaryField(default=None)
```

In my form, I save the image

```
            photograph = cd['photograph'].file.getvalue(),
        )
```

In My view

```
    f = open('my.jpeg', 'bw')
    myfile = File(f)
    myfile.write(student.photograph)
    filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath('my.jpeg'))
    context['urls'] = filepath
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

The image is saved to the database, it is being retrieved successfully.
[Screenshot of the image being saved successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkeMk.png)
My template

The HTML in the template renders well.
If  I copy the HTML into a local file, the image appears well and good.
However, [the image doesn't load properly when I use django.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIANY.png)
Right click > copy image address gives me this: about:blank#blocked

Is it a security or a permissions issue?

Comment: Why don't you use an `ImageField()` or `FileField()` to store images instead of a `BinaryField()`? [The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) state that using a `BinaryField()` is considered bad practise 99% of the time.

Comment: I am using Binary Field because I only need a small jpeg file per user so the performance hit won't be much. Storing the file gives me database integrity. The record and file can not be deleted independently of each other. Are there any other disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, this is what I found.

in HTML

```
<img src = "data/image:jpeg;base64, {{base64_string}}/>
```

in view

```
from django.http import urlsafe_b64encode
return render(request, 'template.html', {'base64_string' : urlsafe_b64encode(myobject.photograph)
```

This works for development. For production, I guess static files could be served the django way.

Comment: If urlsafe_b64encode doesn't work, you can also use base64.b64encode(byte object).